# Green's function co-incidences in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, greens-functions, propagator, classical-field-theory

Is there a deep reason for this Green's function co-incidences in Quantum Field Theory:

When you compute the time ordered vaccuum expectation value of a quantum field, it turns out to be the same as the Green's function of the classical field.

Comment: 1. Write down the LSZ formula for $\langle p\vert q\rangle$ (a single particle propagating). 2. I don't understand what you mean here - how does the path integral of a free particle "derive interaction physics"? Also, that the path integral is a kernel for the differential operator in the evolution equation of the wave function (I'm not sure why you say "a classical field" here, either) is true pretty much by construction. | Finally, please ask only a single question per post - these two questions look unrelated except for both being about Green's functions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. I haven't studied the LSZ formula. Does it resolve the first co-incidence? I have only seen the first co-incidence explicitly computed. 2. I meant that that path integral derives the Green's function, which has the Coulomb potential built into it. So this co-incidence relates interaction physics to free-particle physics. Can you please write an answer about your resolution of this co-incidence? I really thought these two belonged in the same question. I apologise for  breaking site rules

Comment: @ACuriousMind Okay I'll ask a separate question about the second co-incidence